# ASP.NET Core SPAServices Client Side Form Validation VUE2

Tags: validation, asp.net-core-mvc, vuejs2, single-page-application

I haven't been in FE solutions for a while. As a part of my FE education, I would like to create a simple VUE2 SPA app on ASP.NET Core BE using SPAServices/SPATempaltes. In general, I consider this as a great piece of technology, but I came to one problem. How to conduct client side validation. Some time ago I was using jquery validation that was integrated with ASP.NET MVC services. Can someone give me a point (maybe not the exact solution, but the places where to look for) how this can be done nowadays?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Client side Validation in VueJs or any front framework happens using HTML5 and Javascript. Like you did in Jquery all these frameworks exposes different events to subscribe and you can validate user inputs etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found this post to be really helpful in doing your own validation for Vue (using vee-validation).

https://stu.ratcliffe.io/2017/7/23/integrating-vuejs-with-aspnet-core-mvc

Now it isn't using Vue as a SPA, but this is one that talks about validation. He also has a post on utilizing Vue and ASP.NET Core in a SPA here:
https://stu.ratcliffe.io/2017/07/20/vuejs-serverside-rendering-with-aspnet-core

Here is some of the validation code from the first post (in case of link rot):

```
(function (Vue, VeeValidate) {

if (document.querySelector('#contact')) {
Vue.use(VeeValidate);

var app = new Vue({
  el: "#contact",
  data: {
    name: '',
    email: '',
    message: '',
    errorMessage: ''
  },
  methods: {
    send: function () {
      this.$validator.validateAll().then(result => { 
        if (result) {
          this.reset();
          alert('Form submitted!');
        } else {
          this.errorMessage = 'Please fix all validation errors.'
        }
      });
    },
    reset: function () {
      this.name = '';
      this.email = '';
      this.message = '';
      this.errorMessage = '';
      this.$validator.clean();
    }
  }
});
}

})(Vue, VeeValidate);
```

View

```
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Contact";
}
<h2>@ViewData["Title"].</h2>

<div id="contact">
<form v-on:submit.prevent="send">
<div v-if="errorMessage.length" class="alert alert-danger">
  {{ errorMessage }}
</div>
<div :class="{ 'form-group': true, 'has-error': errors.has('name'), 'has-success': name.length && !errors.has('name') }">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input autofocus v-model="name" v-validate="'required|min:5'" class="form-control" name="name" type="text" />
  <span v-show="errors.has('name')" class="text-danger">{{ errors.first('name') }}</span>
</div>
<div :class="{ 'form-group': true, 'has-danger': errors.has('email'), 'has-success': email.length && !errors.has('email') }">
  <label for="email">E-mail</label>
  <input v-model="email" v-validate="'required|email'" class="form-control" name="email" type="text" />
  <span v-show="errors.has('email')" class="text-danger">{{ errors.first('email') }}</span>
</div>
<div :class="{ 'form-group': true, 'has-danger': errors.has('message'), 'has-success': message.length && !errors.has('message') }">
  <label for="message">Message</label>
  <textarea v-model="message" v-validate="'required|min:5'" class="form-control" name="message"></textarea>
  <span v-show="errors.has('message')" class="text-danger">{{ errors.first('message') }}</span>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
</div>
```

The project can be found at:

https://github.com/sturatcliffe/VueDotnetMVC